# Logging to disk in android like circular or ring buffer

Tags: java, android

I need to be able to write logs to disk so that for debugging purposes it can be sent to me by the user. If I use the Log class in android it appears to only have the ability to write to logcat and logcat is not so useful as the relevant logs can disappear after sometime. So for me its important that logs are written to disk and can be recovered later anytime. Therefore I require Logcat like functionality (ring buffer of limited size) but being persisted to disk to persist across App crashes and devices restarts.

Is there any existing class in android that can help me

- write Logs to the disk,
- Is thread safe,
- and implements some kind of ring buffer on disk (so that the log file can not become more than a predefined size and always have most recent logs)

It should also be performant at sizes simliar to the default ring-buffer sizes of the existing Logcat implementation (64kB through to 1MB on higher end devices)

I really do not want to reinvent the wheel and I am happy to use a third-party library for that if I have to , please advise.

Otherwise how could this be implemented with existing Android framework API's and class library?

Comment: I don't recall anything in the Android SDK, but there are [plenty of logging libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/57).

Comment: Sounds like one class, with a couple of static methods. It would be easy to implement yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this class [DiscourseLogger](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/packages/apps/Email/provider_src/com/android/email/mail/transport/DiscourseLogger.java).We used in many of our projects. You will need to modify it but it is a good starting point.

```
    /*
 * Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.android.email.mail.transport;

import com.android.emailcommon.Logging;
import com.android.mail.utils.LogUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A class to keep last N of lines sent to the server and responses received from the server.
 * They are sent to logcat when {@link #logLastDiscourse} is called.
 *
 * <p>This class is used to log the recent network activities when a response parser crashes.
 */
public class DiscourseLogger {
    private final int mBufferSize;
    private String[] mBuffer;
    private int mPos;
    private final StringBuilder mReceivingLine = new StringBuilder(100);

    public DiscourseLogger(int bufferSize) {
        mBufferSize = bufferSize;
        initBuffer();
    }

    private void initBuffer() {
        mBuffer = new String[mBufferSize];
    }

    /** Add a single line to {@link #mBuffer}. */
    private void addLine(String s) {
        mBuffer[mPos] = s;
        mPos++;
        if (mPos >= mBufferSize) {
            mPos = 0;
        }
    }

    private void addReceivingLineToBuffer() {
        if (mReceivingLine.length() > 0) {
            addLine(mReceivingLine.toString());
            mReceivingLine.delete(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Store a single byte received from the server in {@link #mReceivingLine}.  When LF is
     * received, the content of {@link #mReceivingLine} is added to {@link #mBuffer}.
     */
    public void addReceivedByte(int b) {
        if (0x20 <= b && b <= 0x7e) { // Append only printable ASCII chars.
            mReceivingLine.append((char) b);
        } else if (b == '\n') { // LF
            addReceivingLineToBuffer();
        } else if (b == '\r') { // CR
        } else {
            final String hex = "00" + Integer.toHexString(b);
            mReceivingLine.append("\\x" + hex.substring(hex.length() - 2, hex.length()));
        }
    }

    /** Add a line sent to the server to {@link #mBuffer}. */
    public void addSentCommand(String command) {
        addLine(command);
    }

    /** @return the contents of {@link #mBuffer} as a String array. */
    /* package for testing */ String[] getLines() {
        addReceivingLineToBuffer();

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        final int start = mPos;
        int pos = mPos;
        do {
            String s = mBuffer[pos];
            if (s != null) {
                list.add(s);
            }
            pos = (pos + 1) % mBufferSize;
        } while (pos != start);

        String[] ret = new String[list.size()];
        list.toArray(ret);
        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * Log the contents of the {@link mBuffer}, and clears it out.  (So it's okay to call this
     * method successively more than once.  There will be no duplicate log.)
     */
    public void logLastDiscourse() {
        String[] lines = getLines();
        if (lines.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        LogUtils.w(Logging.LOG_TAG, "Last network activities:");
        for (String r : getLines()) {
            LogUtils.w(Logging.LOG_TAG, "%s", r);
        }
        initBuffer();
    }
}
```